# Foreign element in Svg

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg

I have an svg element in my page with several polygons that together create a sort of "map", I'd like to put an `<img>` element in these polygon so I can have access to its parent Id (the polygon owner) and know how many images I have inside a polygon.

How can I do it?

```
<div id="Div-mappa" >
    <svg id="Mappa" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <polygon
            class="regione"
            id="Area1" 
            onclick="attiva(this.id)"
            points="1,0,1,110,6,107,14,103,19,103,24,109,29,113,31,116,35,119,37,121,44,119,51,116,53,112,60,110,63,106,65,99,64,90,64,85,64,77,66,73,68,68,69,64,72,64,74,65,76,67,76,69,78,71,81,68,86,62,91,59,99,57,107,56,114,54,126,52,129,46,132,40,134,37,131,31,127,27,126,21,126,17,127,12,127,7,127,4,127,2,128,0"/>

        <polygon 
            class="regione"
            id="Area2" 
            onclick="attiva(this.id)"
            points="129,1,129,11,128,18,129,23,132,30,134,36,138,40,147,43,149,46,149,51,159,53,168,55,172,55,170,60,168,64,168,68,170,73,174,78,175,82,174,86,174,92,175,98,178,104,186,107,198,106,206,107,217,103,224,103,232,99,239,97,240,92,238,88,244,90,249,92,255,97,256,98,258,93,263,88,265,84,263,79,258,71,257,65,258,60,261,57,261,53,260,46,263,42,265,40,265,35,264,32,261,27,261,24,262,20,265,16,265,13,263,9,263,6,263,4,262,2,261,0"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Some SVG code please!?

Comment: There are 60 polygon like these in my svg, i posted the first 2 like examples but they are all similar

Comment: you could use some non-functional attribute to store the owner id in the DOM.